# Chrome and Auto execute a javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there a way to execute some javascript on load a web site.
For example I want to hide facebook chat and I want to execute 
document.getElementById('pagelet_chat_home').style.display = "none" on loading a site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap the needed actions into a greasmonkey script - Chrome supports greasemonkey user scripts out of the box and converts them into a plugins automatically.

Save the following as `script.user.js` and open it with Chrome. Chrome should detect it as a plugin and install it. Didn't check if it actually works but there shouldn't be any problems.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Hide Pagelet
// @namespace     hide_pagelet
// @description   An example Greasemonkey script that hides a pagelet
// @include       http://*.facebook.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById('pagelet_chat_home').style.display = "none";
```

Comment: thanks. And what about other browsers ( IE, Firefox ). Are they support greasmonkey script or can use other ways.

Comment: Firefox supports Greasemonkey scripts through a plugin. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey